# Как написать регулярное выражение по условию для валидации телефонного номера

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно проверять телефонный номер на валидность по следующему условию:

1) Минимальная длина 10 символов
2) Максимальная длина 18 символов
3) если есть знак "+" то он может быть только первым символом
4) "-" может находиться в любом месте в любом порядке

Я нашел только правило на "-" в любом порядке ("^[0-9\-]*$"), но как добавить сюда остальные условия?

Comment: У меня есть своя реализация, но со своими ньюансами(в каждом проекте они свои). Уделите немного времени https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html там должно быть все что вам может понадобится.

Comment: В качестве валидатора при вводе номеров тлф. или еще чего, используем удобную библиотеку от разработчиков Тинькофф. Сылка есть [в этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/company/tinkoff/blog/312968/)

Comment: А можно про `-`  поконкретнее? Может ли он встретиться в любом количестве? Подряд? В начале/конце строки? А "символы" - это цифры? 10-18 цифр (т.е. `-` в счет не входят)? Лучше добавить пример валидных и невалидных строк, иначе на воросы относительно регулярок трудно отвечать.

Comment: Попробуйте [`s.matches("\\+?(?:-?\\d){10,17}")`](https://regex101.com/r/Yj7UGX/1). [Java-демо](http://ideone.com/04FeS4).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну пока, что у меня вышло вот так

```
public static boolean isPhoneNumberValid(final String iPhoneNumber)
{
    boolean result = true;

    if (iPhoneNumber == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(iPhoneNumber) || iPhoneNumber.length() < 10 || iPhoneNumber.length() > 18 || !Patterns.PHONE.matcher(iPhoneNumber).matches())
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если это все условия которые вам необходимо учесть, измените ваше регулярное выражение
Добавьте в начале \\+? чтобы указать что может быть от 0 до 1 символа "+".
И в конце замените "*"(любое кол-во символов включая 0) на {10,18} чтобы указать точный диапазон кол-ва элементов.
Итого у вас получится вот такое регулярное выражение соответствующее вашим небольшим требованиям.

"^\\+?[0-9][0-9\\-]{9,17}$"

Немного поправил ваш кусок регулярки чтобы номер на начинался с "-".

Comment: тут пары сплешей не хватает, должно быть так `"^\\+?[0-9][0-9\\-]{10,17}$"` , а во вторых у меня почему то все равно не работает...

Comment: "+0----------" валидно по-вашему?

Comment: @YuraIvanov по вашему "+0----------" не соотетствует -> 4) "-" может находиться в любом месте в любом порядке ? Или я тут должен продумывать за автора все ньюансы и писать ему абсолютно идеальное решение?

Comment: По-моему, глупо писать ответ ради ответа, не выяснив "всех нюансов". Посмотрите на заголовок вопроса и на свой ответ. Заходящие из поиска извлекут пользу из вашего ответа или ее будет больше от вашего комментария под вопросом?

Comment: @YuraIvanov каких ньюансов, есть четко поставленная задача, есть моменты с которыми человек справился и моменты с которыми ему нужна помощь. Я дал ответ с описанием того с чем у человека были проблемы. Что не так с моим ответом!?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko значит у вас проблема в чем то другом. Вот валидатор регулярный выражений http://regexr.com/ учтите что в нем чтобы заэкранировать какой либо символ используется один слэш, но в коде вам приходится использовать два чтобы заэкранировать слеш который должен экранировать символ.

Comment: Ну так, а в чем тут может быть проблема вот код `String regexStr = "^\\+?[0-9][0-9\\-]{10,17}$";
  boolean result = iPhoneNumber.matches(regexStr);` , `iPhoneNumber = "0523681927"` и `result` всегда равен `false`... мне кажется проблема в выражении

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko блин мой косяк, извиняюсь, я когда исправил чтобы первая цифра не могла быть "-" забыл на еденицу уменьшить минимальное кол-во вхождений. {10,17} 10 поменяйте на 9.